# Is there a way to compare the post content before and after update?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have already tried the `post_updated` hook but that does not seem to work when Gutenberg is enabled, both $before_post and $after_post contain the same value.

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/47908

I cannot find any other straightforward way to accomplish the same, none of the other hooks have helped either. For eg. I tried getting the post content in the `pre_post_update` hook but that did not work either.

Comment: What about keeping both in `$_SESSION` variables?

Comment: I'm not sure when you want to do this (after the saving is complete?), but there is a function to get the revisions of a post `wp_get_post_revisions( $post_id, $args );`, which you could then use to pull the contents of the most recent (new), and second most recent (previous) revision.

Comment: Is this method guaranteed to give the before version? I thought autosaves are also saved as revisions. If not, is there a way to guarantee it? @tmdesigned

Comment: @mitkosoft You mean storing the before post in session variable when post is opened and then comparing it when user updates?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **wp_get_post_revision( $post );** function.

Later on when you get post, you can compare $revisionedPost->post_content and your $post->post_content

here is reference for wp_get_post_revision()
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_revision

Comment: Is this method guaranteed to give the before version? I thought autosaves are also saved as revisions. If not, is there a way to guarantee it?